# Склонение слова товар в virtuemart 2

Tags: joomla, virtuemart

Не могу понять как правильно сделать склонение слов в virtuemart 2, там у меня на стандартная мини корзина

```
<div class="mc-header">
        <a class="mc-yourcart" href="<?php echo JRoute::_('index.php?option=com_virtuemart&view=cart');?>" title="<?php JText::_('Mycart');?>">
            <span class="mc-totalproduct" data-hover="<?php echo count($cart->products); ?>"><?php echo count($cart->products); ?></span>
        </a>

        <?php  echo (count($cart->products) >1) ?JText::_('ITEMS'): JText::_('ITEM');?>

    </div>
```

Пытался сделать так вместо `echo (count($cart->products) >1) ?JText::_('ITEMS'): JText::_('ITEM');` вставил

```
    function sklonenie($n, $forms) {
     return $n%10==1&&$n%100!=11?$forms[0]:($n%10>=2&&$n%10<=4&&($n%100<10||$n%100>=20)?$forms[1]:$forms[2]);
     }

    $total_products = $amount ." ". sklonenie($amount , array('товар', 'товара', 'товаров') ) ;
&nbsp;
    if ($amount < 1) {

    $total_products ='В корзине ничего нет, самое время что-нибудь купить';

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function plural($number, array $words) {
    $cases = array(2, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2);
    return $words[($number % 100 > 4 && $number % 100 < 20) ? 2 : $cases[min($number % 10, 5)]];
}

echo plural(6, array('товар', 'товара', 'товаров'));
```

Смотрите [результат](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/1bc8681744a128a7e5ef99cc6d191b7596226c3e).

Comment: А вы у ТС не видете в вопросе функцию `sklonenie()` что ли? P.S. ТС не просит функцию склонения, он не понимает, что делает при замене кода (судя по тому что на что он заменил).